# Why is boost::asio::async_write causing a crash?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

My Server runs fine till a client connects then it trys to send a message to the client. Here is the function for sending a message to the client.  When this code runs it crashes with the error

Unhandled exception at 0x6351117C (msvcr110d.dll) in SERVER.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000002.

```
    template <typename T, typename Handler>
    void AsyncWrite(const T& t, Handler handler)
    {
        std::ostringstream archiveStream;
        boost::archive::text_oarchive archive(archiveStream);
        archive << t;
        outboundData = archiveStream.str();

        std::ostringstream headerStream;
        headerStream << std::setw(headerLength) << std::hex << outboundData.size();
        if (!headerStream || headerStream.str().size() != headerLength)
        {
            boost::system::error_code error(boost::asio::error::invalid_argument);
            socket.get_io_service().post(boost::bind(handler, error));
            return;
        }
        outboundHeader = headerStream.str();

        std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer> buffers;
        buffers.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(outboundHeader));
        buffers.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(outboundData));
        boost::asio::async_write(socket, buffers, handler);
    }
```

Edit: Don't know if it matters but im following this example

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/serialization/connection.hpp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify that the lifespan of the object containing `outboundData` and `outboundHeader` exceeds that of the `async_write` operation.

This is done in the associated [server.cpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/serialization/server.cpp) example, by managing `connection` via a `shared_ptr`, and binding the `shared_ptr` to the handler.  Here are the relevant excerpts from the code:

```
/// Constructor opens the acceptor and starts waiting for the first incoming
/// connection.
server(...)
  : acceptor_(...)
{
  // Start an accept operation for a new connection.
  connection_ptr new_conn(new connection(acceptor_.get_io_service()));
  acceptor_.async_accept(new_conn->socket(),
      boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error, new_conn));
}  

/// Handle completion of a accept operation.
void handle_accept(const boost::system::error_code& e, connection_ptr conn)
{
  if (!e)
  {
    // Successfully accepted a new connection. Send the list of stocks to the
    // client. The connection::async_write() function will automatically
    // serialize the data structure for us.
    conn->async_write(...,
        boost::bind(&server::handle_write, this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error, conn));
  }
  ...
}

/// Handle completion of a write operation.
void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& e, connection_ptr conn)
{
  // Nothing to do. The socket will be closed automatically when the last
  // reference to the connection object goes away.
}
```

The `connection`, which contains `outboundData` and `outboundHeader`, is created and managed by a `shared_ptr` in the `server` constructor.  The `shared_ptr` is then bound to the `server::handle_accept()`, the handler for `async_accept`.  Within `server::handle_accept()`, the connection is bound to `server::handle_write()`, the handler for `connection::async_write()`.  Although `server::handle_write()` does nothing, it is critical in the chain, as it keeps the `connection` object alive through its bound argument.

---

One could argue that it is less intrusive if the `connection` guaranteed its lifespan would exceed the `async_write` operation without imposing the requirement on the caller.  A common idiomatic solution for this is to have `connection` inherit from [`enable_shared_from_this`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/smart_ptr/enable_shared_from_this.html).  When a class inherits from `enable_shared_from_this`, it provides a `shared_from_this()` member function that returns a valid `shared_ptr` instance to `this`.

Here is a complete example based on the `server` and `connection` objects in the Boost.Asio [serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/serialization/) example.

```
#include <string>

#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/protect.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

class connection
  : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<connection>
{
public:

  /// @brief Constructor.
  connection(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    : socket_(io_service)
  {
    std::cout << "connection(): " << this << std::endl;
  }

  ~connection()
  {
    std::cout << "~connection(): " << this << std::endl;
  }

  /// @brief Get the underlying socket. Used for making a connection 
  ///        or for accepting an incoming connection.
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket()
  {
    return socket_;
  } 

  /// @brief Asynchronously write data to the connection, invoking
  ///        handler upon completion or failure.
  template <typename Handler>
  void async_write(std::string data, Handler handler)
  {
    // Perform processing on data and copy to member variables.
    using std::swap;
    swap(data_, data);

    // Create a buffer sequence.
    boost::array<boost::asio::const_buffer, 1> buffers = {{
      boost::asio::buffer(data_)
    }};

    std::cout << "connection::async_write() " << this << std::endl;

    // Write to the socket.
    boost::asio::async_write(
        socket_,
        buffers, // Buffer sequence copied, not the underlying buffers.
        boost::bind(&connection::handle_write<Handler>,
          shared_from_this(), // Keep connection alive throughout operation.
          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
          handler));
  }

private:

  /// @brief Invokes user provided handler.  This member function
  ///        allows for the connection object's lifespan to be
  ///        extended during the binding process.
  template <typename Handler>
  void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error,
                    Handler handler)
  {
    std::cout << "connection::handle_write() " << this << std::endl;
    handler(error);
  }

private:
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket_;
  std::string data_;
};

class server
{
public:
  /// @brief Constructor opens an acceptor, waiting for incoming connection.
  server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
         unsigned short port)
    : acceptor_(io_service,
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port))
  {
    start_accept();
  }

private:

  /// @brief Start an accept operation for a new connection.
  void start_accept()
  {
    boost::shared_ptr<connection> new_conn =
        boost::make_shared<connection>(
          boost::ref(acceptor_.get_io_service()));
    acceptor_.async_accept(new_conn->socket(),
        boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error, new_conn));
  }

  /// @brief Handle completion of a accept operation.
  void handle_accept(const boost::system::error_code& error,
                     boost::shared_ptr<connection> conn)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      // Successfully accepted a new connection. Write data to it.
      conn->async_write("test data",
          boost::protect(
            boost::bind(&server::handle_write, this,
              boost::asio::placeholders::error)));
    }

    // Start accepting another connection.
    start_accept();
  }

  void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    std::cout << "server::handle_write()" << std::endl;
  }

private:
  /// The acceptor object used to accept incoming socket connections.
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor_;

};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    // Check command line arguments.
    if (argc != 2)
    {
      std::cerr << "Usage: server <port>" << std::endl;
      return 1;
    }
    unsigned short port = boost::lexical_cast<unsigned short>(argv[1]);

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    server server(io_service, port);
    io_service.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Running the program, and connecting from another terminal resulted in the following output:

```
connection(): 0x8cac18c
connection::async_write() 0x8cac18c
connection(): 0x8cac1e4
connection::handle_write() 0x8cac18c
server::handle_write()
~connection(): 0x8cac18c
```

Notice how the `connection` object's lifespan extends to be at least that of the `async_write` operation.  The modified API allows for the `server` to not have to manage the `connection`, as the object will manage itself.  Note that `boost::protect` is required due to the nested `boost::bind`.  There are alternatives to this that will not place the burden on the caller, such as packing the bound handler in a tuple, as is done in `connection::async_read()` within the Boost.Asio example.

Comment: Although your full example based on the Serialization example took away the serialization and only sends a string "test data" It did help me fix my issue.  I think my object containing the Connection was getting deleted early and shared_ptr seems to fix that

Answer (score 2):

This is fraught with peril:

```
std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer> buffers;
buffers.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(outboundHeader));
buffers.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(outboundData));
boost::asio::async_write(socket, buffers, handler);
```

Because `buffers` is a local object with automatic storage duration, it is going out of scope before the `async_write()` is complete.  That alone shouldn't be an issue (this object is copied as necessary).

However, your actual data (held in `outboundHeader` and `outboundData`) are also from local objects with automatic storage duration, so they also are going out of scope before the `async_write()` is complete.

You have to ensure that the objects passed into the `async_*` functions have lifetimes that extend to the point that the handler is called.

Here's a possible workaround, though it requires that your `Handler` objects are changed to accept the data (that has been written in your case) as a parameter.

```
// new format of the handler
void Handler(std::shared_ptr<OutboundData> written);

struct OutboundData
{
   std::string header;
   std::string data;
};

// guarantee the lifetime of the OutboundData block
auto outbound_data = std::make_shared<OutboundData>();

// copy the contents (to send) in...
outbound_data->header = outboundHeader;
outbound_data->data = outboundData;

std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer> buffers;
buffers.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(outbound_data->header));
buffers.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(outbound_data->header));

// send the data, handler(outbound_data) will be called upon 
// completion (success or failure)
boost::asio::async_write(socket, buffers, boost::bind(handler, outbound_data));
```

Also note that for robustness, generally your handlers should accept the possible error conditions, so proper action can be taken in the case of a failure.  That would look something like this:

```
void Handler(
  const boost::system::error_code& err,    // The error code
  std::shared_ptr<OutboundData> written);   // the data written (or not)

// calling async_write, while binding the appropriate parameter(s)
boost::asio::async_write(
  socket,
  buffers,
  boost::bind(handler, outbound_data, boost::asio::placeholders::error);
```

Comment: shouldn't the outboundHeader and outboundData last as long as the class is still there? since they are outside any methods?

Comment: If they are member variables, yes.  I missed that detail.  Does the class itself have a long enough lifetime?

Comment: well the connection class is a member variable of a class called Client.  When a client connects a Client object is created and stored in a std::list<Client> clientlist by the following

Client client(conn, logger_);
clientList.push_back(client);